# c# Using a Proxy in WebBrowser with login and password

Tags: c#, proxy, webbrowser-control

I use Gecko browser (from Mozilla).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Skybound.Gecko;

namespace shit_browser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Xpcom.Initialize(@"C:\XPCOM");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.ru", 0, "", null, "");
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use a proxy. Log in via login, password and ip. How can this be realized?

Comment: would this help --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/41526088/1132334

Comment: @dlatikay, no, I need with login and password

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium - Web Browser Automation.

```
         ChromeDriver _driver;
         WebDriverWait _wait;

        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("......./homepage.htm");
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("...../index.htm");
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("....../login.jsp");

       _wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("kullaniciAdi")));

        var userNameField = _driver.FindElementById("username");
        var userPasswordField = _driver.FindElementById("password");
        var loginButton = 
       _driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='Login']");

        userNameField.SendKeys("USERNAME");
        userPasswordField.SendKeys("PASSWORD");

        loginButton.Click();
```

Comment: you do not understand, I do not need authorization somewhere. I need to use a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Hmm sorry, i found like this maybe it'll work, didnt try.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


  // Create proxy class object
  Proxy p=new Proxy();


  // Set HTTP Port to 7777
  p.setHttpProxy("localhost:7777");

  // Create desired Capability object
  DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();


  // Pass proxy object p
  cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, p);


  // Open  firefox browser
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(cap);

  // from here onwards code will be same as normal script

 }


}
```